# How to fix specific CSS position scaling in percentage

Tags: css, position, scaling, percentage

How to fix specific CSS position scaling in percentages?
[The jump occurs during manual scaling in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTTfP.png)
code:

```
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5b576cm/2/
```

Comment: Which element do you want to scale?

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding using percentage in width and height as much as you can, they are very messy.

First of all, have your top containers with the same fixed width:

```
section.h-banner {
width: 66.444%;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
left: -3.666%;
```

}

then align the child container

```
.container-header {
text-align: center;
margin: 0px -12%;
left: 12.7%;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
```

}

but again, very messy..